# Edit the content of a text block in a list C# (WPF Application)

Tags: c#, wpf, list, random, textblock

So I have five text blocks I've added to a list, and each one is supposed to get its own random number between one and 6.

I know I can just do a new int for each text block (`int randomNumberOne, randomNumberTwo, etc`) but I'm trying to see if I can figure out how to make a list and a for each loop to work.

Is there some way to edit the content of a TextBox in a list as it goes through? If there is, I haven't found any way to do so.

Here's my code so far.

```
List<TextBlock> randomBoxList = new List<TextBlock>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            randomBoxList.Add(randomBoxOne);
            randomBoxList.Add(randomBoxTwo);
            randomBoxList.Add(randomBoxThree);
            randomBoxList.Add(randomBoxFour);
            randomBoxList.Add(randomBoxFive);
        }

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomNumber;

    private void randomButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TextBlock textBlock in randomBoxList)
        {
            randomNumber = randomGenerator.Next(1, 7);
            //Code to change randomBox content goes here. 
        }
    }
```

Comment: wpf or wnforms?

Comment: WPF. Sorry, I'll edit my post to make that clear.

Comment: I recommend MVVM for this. You can then bind it to ContentControl and loop through a list.

Comment: What I was about to suggest that. it might be a bit of work if you define the buttons to be in a loop container type of element like a list, etc

Comment: While using MVVM is definitely a good suggestion, you could also just do `textBlock.Text = randomNumber.ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is WPF, you should just be able to use textBlock.Text property like so:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock> randomBoxList = new List<System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        randomBoxList.Add(randomBoxOne);
        randomBoxList.Add(randomBoxTwo);
        randomBoxList.Add(randomBoxThree);
        randomBoxList.Add(randomBoxFour);
        randomBoxList.Add(randomBoxFive);
    }

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomNumber;

    private void randomButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock textBlock in randomBoxList)
        {
            randomNumber = randomGenerator.Next(1, 7);
            textBlock.Text = randomNumber.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Had no idea that was a thing you could do. I figured there was some way to do that but I couldn't figure it out for the life of me. Must've not been looking too hard. Thanks so much!